# Difference between "report" and "report on"

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage

> 1  : to give information about (something) in a newspaper or on
>   television or radio
>
> [+ object]
>
> Their job is to report the news accurately and fairly.
>
> **[no object]— often + on**
>
> **He reports on political news for a local TV station.**
>
> 2  : to tell people about (something) : to make a report about
>   (something)
>
> [+ object]
>
> He was asked to report the details of the meeting.
>
> **— often + on**
>
> **She reported on the project to her manager.**
>
> From Merriam Webster Learner’s Dictionary
>
> http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/report

---

> 1 NEWS [intransitive, transitive] to give people information about
>   recent events, especially in newspapers and on television and radio →
>   reporter
>
> This is Gavin Williams, reporting from the United Nations in New York.
>
> **report on**
>
> The Times sent her to Bangladesh to report on the floods.
>
> 3 JOB/WORK [intransitive, transitive] to tell someone about what has
>   been happening, or what you are doing as part of your job
>
> **report (to somebody) on something**
>
> I’ve asked him to come back next week and **report on** his progress.
>
> From Longman Dictionary
>
> https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/report

I have quoted relevant definitions from Merriam Webster and Longman Dicitonary.

What is the difference between “report” and “report on”?

Take these two examples from Merriam Webster Learner’s Dictionary. Can I delete “on” without changing the meanings of the sentences?

1. He reports on political news for a local TV station.
2. She reported on the project to her manager.

Comment: Hello, lux. While the quoted material from MWLD is very good _as far as it goes_, other senses / subsenses of 'report', preferably with example sentences, need to be considered. Can you link to MWLD, please. Have you checked in other dictionaries? // 'She reported [back] on the project to her manager' is idiomatic, and means she filled her manager in on what had been planned / achieved.  'She reported the project to her manager' is unidiomatic, I'd say. It's perhaps acceptable if she's informing her manager that a covert or obscure conference has taken / is taking ...  place.

Comment: Yes, I have edited accordingly. I have only listed relevant definitions from the two dictionaries.

Comment: yes, I see your point. That is why you asked me to list more sub-senses. 4 
[+ object] : to tell the police, fire department, etc., about (something, such as a crime or accident). 5 
[+ object] : to tell someone with authority about (someone who has broken a rule, done something wrong, etc.)  from MWLD.

Comment: I think it indicates a person, i.e. first or third. If someone 'reports _on_' something, they are apart from the event. Simply 'reporting' implies they were connected with the event.

Answer (score -1):

No. To report, say a successful project, you can say quite simply, “The project was successful”. But to report *on* the successful project, you’d be expected to provide details.